# server-client communication and forwarding steps

Tags: c, concurrency, process, pipe, fork

Firstly, I don't need a code. I can write codes too! I need your advices and ideas. I have two C files one is `server`, the other one is `client-maker`. The server has `4` children(employees of server) to respond incoming requests from children(clients) of the client-maker, that is, client-maker forks number of `3, 6, ..` children subject to argument specifying client(children) number to be `fork`ed. There is a well-known FIFO which is known by server ,as well as all children, to receive requests from clients(forked children by client-maker).

*The server(employer of the 4 children) forwards the requests orderly to the idle children.* Each of the children does equally similar jobs. *The child done its job must tell its parent(server) that I'm ready to get a new job(answer to client).*

My problems are as follows,

1. How does the server forward the incoming requests to the idle
   children(the 4 children of server)? What is the way/method that I need to use?
2. How can I know the child is idle at that time?
3. How can the child tell its parent(server) that I'm ready to get a
   new job(answer to client)? By what way/method?

I can't start writing my program since I can't answer the questions. I mean - since I can't build its structure. -

Please, propose solutions only with FIFO or PIPE IPCs and signals.

Maybe I can use a counter which is adjusted by the 4 children by guarding with a semaphore. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [mcve].